# Less javascript code for this loop animation?

Tags: javascript

I've done this simple animation but i have a feeling i've writted to much lines of code for such a simple task. Is there a way to achieve the same result but with less code ?

https://jsfiddle.net/qw82Lwy0/1/

```
function myMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate");
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
  var flag = true;

  function frame() {
    if (flag) {
      pos++;
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
      if (pos == 350) {
        flag = false;
      }
    } else if (!flag) {
      pos--;
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
      if (pos == 0) {
        flag = true;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

P.S: No jquery or css animation, just javascript.

Comment: How about removing all those duplicate lines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using the flag and a seperate code for the 2 conditions you could just flip the incrementer like so:

```
function myMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate");
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
  var changeVal = 1;

  function frame() {
      pos+=changeVal;
      if ((pos >= 350) || (pos <= 0)) changeVal *= -1;
      elem.style.top = elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Animations can now be done in modern browsers using CSS. For example, your javascript animation can be condensed to just a few lines using a CSS transition.

See MDN for more details and examples of [transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) and [animations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Animations/Using_CSS_animations).

**Run the code snippet below to try**

```js
window.ball.addEventListener('transitionend', toggle);

function toggle() {
  window.ball.classList.toggle('move');
}
```

```css
.animation {
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightyellow;
  border: 1px solid gray;
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

#ball {
  transition-property: left top background-color;
  transition-duration: 2s;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 12px;
  height: 25px;
  width: 25px;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}

#ball.move {
  background-color: blue;
  left: 175px;
  top: 175px;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="toggle()">Start</button>
<div class="animation"><div id="ball"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you could shorten your `frame()` function like so:

```
function myMove() {
  var elem = document.getElementById("animate");
  var pos = 0;
  var id = setInterval(frame, 5);
  var flag = true;

  function frame() {
    if (flag) {
      pos++;
      if (pos == 350) {
        flag = false;
      }
    } else { // since you are checking if flag is true, the only other answer is false
      pos--;
      if (pos == 0) {
        flag = true;
      }
    }
    elem.style.top = pos + 'px'; // since this occurs in both cases
    elem.style.left = pos + 'px'; // you can do it afterward
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a function with 3 paraneters :  posAdd, flagValue and posValue

```
   function frame(posAdd,flagValue,posValue) {
    if (flagValue) {
      pos=pos+posAdd;
      elem.style.top = pos + 'px';
      elem.style.left = pos + 'px';
      if (pos == posValue) {
        flag =  !flagValue;
    }
  }
}
```

And call it twice :  frame(1,true,350)
And frame(-1,false,0)

Comment: I saw too late that you call frame() inside a setInterval...so my answer would not fit in that case.